# Separate Activity for different users

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have my android project where there are two different user types: an admin and a normal user. 
I actually found a solution here not specifically a solution since it does not work for me.

**Home Fragment.java**

```
public View onCreateView(@NonNull final LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable final ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
    final String uid = user.getUid();
    Query userQuery = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("User").child(uid).child("isAdmin");

    userQuery.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {

        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            String type = dataSnapshot.child("isAdmin").getValue().toString();

            if(type.equals("true")){

                loadMenuBeachAdmin();

                FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) homeView.findViewById(R.id.fab);
                fab.show();
      }
}
```

**Database**

[image]

**The error I'm getting:**

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method
        'java.lang.String java.lang.Object.toString()' on a null object reference at 
com.example.batangasbeachhousesfinal.HomeFragment$1.onDataChange(HomeFragment.java:92)
```

which is the String `type = dataSnapshot.child("isAdmin").getValue().toString();`

Comment: Try to put a breakpoint in that line and debug the value of dataSnapshot, of dataSnapshot.child("isAdmin")... and try to see what's happening

Comment: @denis_lor is it possible that the reason I'm getting the null object reference is that I was not able to get the uid right from the sign in page?

Comment: @Reymand did you try my answer?

Comment: @PeterHaddad yes and that works. thank you for the help. Kinda new to it. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this:

```
 Query userQuery = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("User").child(uid).child("isAdmin");
userQuery.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        String type = dataSnapshot.child("isAdmin").getValue().toString();
        if(type.equals("true")){
            loadMenuBeachAdmin();


            FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) homeView.findViewById(R.id.fab);
            fab.show();

   }
}
```

into this:

```
Query userQuery = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("User").child(uid);
userQuery.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        String type = dataSnapshot.child("isAdmin").getValue().toString();
        if(type.equals("true")){
            loadMenuBeachAdmin();


            FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) homeView.findViewById(R.id.fab);
            fab.show();

  }
}
```

Your dataSnapshot is already at child `isAdmin`, so you need to go one step up and then you will be able to retrieve the `isAdmin` child.